# iOS app structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I am very new to iOS and is hoping someone with experience will be able to provide me with some insight into the program structure/architecture of an iOS app which sells books. For instance the News stand application.

Are those books additional programs which run 'outside' the newsstand app or are they modules which are loaded inside the parent app? And how would you reference them inside the appstore?

I would like to build a bookshelf for some books. Each book are built using Cocos2D (works like a game) and needs to be sold individually, but they also need to 'belong' to my bookshelf. The bookshelf will need to manage i.e. 'save, edit, delete' all books previously downloaded etc.

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance? Since I don't understand the architecture, I also have no idea where to start my search.

Many thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Simbul/baker/wiki/Tutorial-for-Newsstand-with-Free-issues  https://github.com/Simbul/baker/wiki/Tutorial-for-Newsstand-with-In-App-Purchase... try these

Comment: Charan this is really interesting. Many thanks!

Comment: Charan this is very close! the only problem I foresee with this approach is it is HTML based. If you consider the amount of js that will need to go into this as you apply gravity and sounds etc, it may end up being more work than Cocos2D?

Comment: Based on the information you provided, I would start at the introductions to iOS & Cocoa touch videos from all the WWDC years.

Comment: http://www.bakerframework.com/books/ Ok. Im sold. Thanks Charan

Answer (score 0):

I think you should break down your problem into small parts or modules.
First make learn about cocos2d.Then search about `UICollectionView` to make shelf like view.Then 
integrate UICollectionView into Cocos2d.
For `UICollectionView` read [*This*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

and also look at [*This Tutorial*](http://maniacdev.com/2012/12/example-creating-a-magazine-rack-view-using-uicollectionview)

Comment: I will have to break it down. Thanks for the links :) Lemme study them a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To save the books, you can use NSUserDefaults. Would you actually be getting actual books or would you be making your own? You can look up thenewboston on YouTube and learn how to actually make simple apps.

Comment: I would be making my own. Thx